Color specific voice in chord notation
How to combine two voices with same rhythm (but if solution works with different rhythms thats a bonus) and color only specific voice within chord like notation.
What I would like to is shown after double bar (second part), but without actual chord like notation.
Also note, that sometimes voices could go across as shown in 2nd and 4th bar, so always corect voice should be colored in chord. Doing it with single chords <a2 a2> would be not viable in big scores.
Example producing incorrectly colored all note heads in first bar.

\version "2.25.20"
\score {
    \relative d' {
        \clef "treble" \time 2/4 \key bes \major \transposition bes

          % FIRST PART - INCORRECT COLORING
          \partCombine
            \relative {
              \override NoteHead.color = #red
 
              bes'8 8 8 8 es, es es es
            
              \revert NoteHead.color
            }
            \relative { g'8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 }
        \bar "||"
        
        % SECOND PART - CORRECT COLORING (but missing chord like notation)
        \new Voice <<
            \relative {
              \override NoteHead.color = #red
            
              bes'8 8 8 8 es, es es es
            
              \revert NoteHead.color
            }
            \\
            \relative { g'8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 }
        >>
    }
}

